# Can I use mailto and send a form in flask app?

Tags: python, html, flask

I've seen a few problems like this but they have a different answer than I was hoping so here I am.

I am planning to send mail details such that the client's mail app opens with the message sent via the form.

Thing is though, I've seen it being doable with PHP but I am running a Flask app.

So is there a way to do it using Python?

This is my form code:

```
<form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate" action="mailto:mail@gmail.com?subject=feedback&body=message">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2"><label>Name</label><input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" required="" placeholder="Name"><small class="form-text text-danger help-block"></small></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2"><label>Email Address</label><input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" required="" placeholder="Email Address"><small class="form-text text-danger help-block"></small></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-5 pb-2"><textarea class="form-control" id="message" required="" placeholder="Message" rows="5"></textarea><small class="form-text text-danger help-block"></small></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="success"></div>
                    <div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" id="sendMessageButton" type="submit">Send</button></div>
</form>
```

What I am looking to do is send a subject and content that is present in the textarea element as the body.

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/

Comment: How do I set this up for when a client clicks the mailto link since I won't know the client's SMTP server and all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself with a workaround using redirect and request and it worked.

```
@app.route('/test',methods=['POST'])
def test():
    mess=request.form['textarea']
    return redirect('mailto:test@email.com?body='+str(mess))
```

In the form what I changed was

```
<form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" novalidate="novalidate" action="{{url_for('test'}}" method="POST">
```